# 'OnActivityResult' Callback isn't invoked in fragment subclass?? after compatibility pack rev 2.0

Tags: android

I have problem with 'onActivityResult' method within Fragment
class...i mean it(onActivityResult Callback) isn't called after
activity finished with setting some result for its invoker...

so i tried to search any relevant information or issues about this
problem....i've found some issues related to compatible pack Rev
2.0....

now i'm using most update version of compatible pack v4(Rev 6) but
still i have same problem...

here the relevant part of my code....

when start activity ===========================

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NoteActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(Note._ID, id);
startActivityForResult(intent, NoteActivity.REQUEST_OPEN);
```

> Note : NoteActivity.REQUEST_OPEN = 0x01;

when return from activity==========================

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
finish();
```

in the 'onActivityResult' callback=====================

```
@Override
       public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intentdata) {
               super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
               Log.e(tag, "Req Code : "+requestCode+"res Code : "+resultCode);
               switch(requestCode){
               case NoteActivity.REQUEST_OPEN:
                       switch(resultCode){
                       case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                               Log.e(tag, "Given ID is : "+data.getLongExtra(Notes._ID, -1));
                               refresh(SortOrder.DATE);
                               break;<br>
                       case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                               Log.e(tag, "Not Saved");
                               refresh(SortOrder.DATE);
                               break;
                       }
                       break;
               }
       }
```

please help me some good idea for this problem....

> Note : I checked the 'onActivityResult' method in hosting
>   activity as well...but it's called correctly...so I guess 'starting activity' and 'returning from it' have no problem...

BR

Comment: Check this [link](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=15394)

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the containing activity's onActivityResult in order for the fragment's 
onActivityResult to be called.

```
@Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
    }
```

Comment: I said that I checked the 'onActivityResult' methond in hosting activity. and obviosuly it means that I've already overriden onActivtyResult method